# using ifstream to count the appearance of a word

Tags: c++, ifstream

I read this code from C++ Primer( 5th ed,by Stanley B.Lippman)
This code is used for counting the time of appearance of a letter in a file.

I wanna know the function of the 2 parameters of the main function 
and, what is `infile.open(argv[1],infile)`

also, can the parameter of the `infile.open()` not be a const? If not, how can I change the file I want to read from the console but not from the source code.
Here is the code:

```
//enter code here
void runQueries(ifstream &infile)
{
    // infile is an ifstream that is the file we want to query
    TextQuery tq(infile);  // store the file and build the query map
    // iterate with the user: prompt for a word to find and print results
    while (true) {
         cout << "enter word to look for, or q to quit: ";
         string s;
         // stop if we hit end-of-file on the input or if a 'q' is entered
         if (!(cin >> s) || s == "q") break;
         // run the query and print the results
         print(cout, tq.query(s)) << endl;
         }
}

// program takes single argument specifying the file to query

//enter code here 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // open the file from which user will query words

    ifstream infile;

    // open returns void, so we use the comma operator XREF(commaOp) 
    // to check the state of infile after the open

    if (argc < 2 || !(infile.open(argv[1]), infile)) {
        cerr << "No input file!" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

    runQueries(infile);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `argv[1]` is the first command line parameter passed to the program.  An example would be `foo file.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### I wanna know the function of the 2 parameters of the main function

They are number of parameters (`int argc`), and an array of pointers to parameters (`const char* argv[]`), respectively.

Note that `const char* argv[]` and `const char** argv` are equivalent, but I think the former is a bit easier to read.

`argv[0]` typically contains the name of the executable the program was run from.

In your case, your program expects the *second* argument, `argv[1]`, to be the path of the file to open.

---

For example, if you run your program as such:

```
$ myprogram file.txt
```

then

```
argc == 2
argv[0] == "myprogram"
argv[1] == "file.txt"
```

---

> #### what is infile.open(argv[1],infile)

That's not how it's spelled. It's actually `(infile.open(argv[1]), infile)`. This is a bit convoluted way (explained in comments) to open a file, and check whether it opened correctly. This could have been rewritten as:

```
if (argc >= 2) {
    infile.open(argv[1]);
    if (!infile) {
        //handle error
    }
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

But as you can see, this requires using error handling at two places.

---

Frankly, I wouldn't write it like that personally:

```
if (argc < 2)
    throw std::runtime_exception("Requires a filename");

ifstream infile(argv[1]); // at this point we can safely assume we can dereference argv[1]

if (!infile)
    throw std::runtime_exception ("Cannot open file");
```

If I remember correctly, the book introduces exception handling at later stages, so you don't have to change all that right now.

---

> #### also, can the parameter of the infile.open() not be a const?

If a function expects an argument that is `const`, you can pass a non-const one to it too (with the exception of references). However, you're already reading the filename from console (standard input), so I don't see the problem here.